# Trouble getting data from Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having some trouble getting all items from a DynamoDB table. I am following the example from the [AWS GitHub repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/api-cors-lambda-crud-dynamodb/lambdas/get-all.ts). Here is the code I have

```
import {APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2}  from 'aws-lambda';
import {DynamoDB} from 'aws-sdk'

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export async function main(
    event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2,
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> {
    console.log('event ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    const tableName: string = process.env.TABLE_NAME || ""
    const requesterUserGroup = event.pathParameters?.userGroup || ""
    console.log(`Table Name: ${tableName}`)
    console.log(`User group: ${requesterUserGroup}`)

    if(tableName.length == 0) return sendError("No table name provided", 500)

    if(requesterUserGroup.length == 0) return sendError("Requester user group is empty", 400)

    try {
        const params = {
            TableName: tableName
        };
        const response = await dynamoClient.scan(params)
        // console.log(`response: ${response} `)
        return sendSuccess(response.Items)

    }catch (dbError){
        console.log(dbError)
        return sendError(dbError, 500)
    }
}

function sendSuccess(message: any): APIGatewayProxyResultV2 {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message })
    }
}

function sendError(message: string, statusCode: number): APIGatewayProxyResultV2 {
    return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message })
    }
}
```

This is the response I am getting from this

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{}"
}
```

I have double-checked the table name and that I have items in the table (a 1000 items!).

Question: Why am I not getting any items from the table?

Comment: I haven't got around to pagination yet, taught I'd a basic "give me everything" working first.

Comment: @jarmod What do you mean by "you're allowing the client to indicate any table name"? I am getting the table name from an env variable and in the lambda role, I have give it access to only a single table.

Comment: Apologies, mis-read. I see you’re getting it from the Lambda environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed `.promise()`, so it don't await until the request is completed.

```
const response = await dynamoClient.scan(params).promise();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. 
Not sure how I missed the .promise() there, server me right for working at 2 in the morning on a Sunday :(